# Ajax does not giving response properly using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm posting id through ajax to controller. But it does not working, and ajax function giving big data something like table in response. Please view the code and guide me where i'm wrong.

### HTML

```
  <li class="sendRequest">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><!--<img src="images/cart-icon.png" alt="cart" />--></a>
                                                            <div>Add To Container</div>
                                                            <form id="formSend" method="post" >
                                                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" name="sendProductId"  class="pID" />
                                                            </form>
                                                        </li>
```

### JS

```
$( ".sendRequest" ).each(function(index) {
                $(this).on("click", function(){
                    var otherInput = $(this).find('.pID').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"index.php?route=common/personaliseyourflowers",
                        data:otherInput,
                        success:function(response){
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

### Php Code

```
if(isset($this->request->get['sendProductId'])){
        $cookie_value = $this->request->get['sendProductId'];
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30));

        }

        print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Also when i print the global variable of cookie it also giving blank array.

Comment: before calling aajax use console.log(otherInput) and check whether does your selector return proper value?

Comment: I dont think echo $this->request->get['sendProductId'] will give you what you posted, I guess you posted value in "otherInput"

Comment: `otherInput = {'sendProductId':$(this).find('.pID').val()}`

Comment: @PRANAV I have check its working

Comment: @HarshMakani Your code giving me this error `Undefined variable: cookie_name in....` Now I'm using `$_REQUEST['sendProductId']`

Comment: that means now your `if` condition is valid and now issue is in `setcookie`

Comment: @HarshMakani Yes now I'm getting result in print but why so many data getting in response `success:function(response){
                            alert(response);
                        }`

Comment: probably it is due to your any of the `echo`/`print_r` getting in response from the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
data:otherInput,
```

with

```
data:{'sendProductId':otherInput},
```

Answer (score 2):

correct your Ajax call as below.

```
   $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"index.php?route=common/personaliseyourflowers",
                    data:{'sendProductId':otherInput},
                    success:function(response){
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
```